# Python data transfer from a computer to another one (not local) without modifying router and fire wall Python

Tags: python-3.x

Basically, i want to take data from pc **A to send it to B (not local) in python**

I tried using **socket**, then found out that its only working in local, except if you **modify router / firewall.** (atleast, its what i got from google)
But **i dont want to** touch these things. So i would like to know, **is there a way to send data to B like i want?** because i cant really modify routers (if there is a way, but with another module, i still want to know)

Also, i dont care if i need to like switch my server code, and having another language or anything, i just want the client file in python, then a way to send data to another computer

my code with socket, if you know a way to send client's data to server:

```
# echo-client.py
import socket

inputKey = "hi"

#Data transferring via sockets

HOST = "" # The server's hostname or IP address
PORT = 65432  # The port used by the server

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.sendall(bytes(str(inputKey), encoding='utf-8'))
```

```
import socket


#Data receiving via sockets
HOST = ""  
PORT = 65432  


with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    connexion, addr = s.accept()
    with connexion:
        print(f"Connected by {addr}")
        while True:
            data = connexion.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break

            #printing in logs.txt
            with open("logs.txt","wb") as log:
                log.write(data)
```

Comment: If you're trying to connect across the internet and a firewall is blocking access to that port there isn't much you can do with basic socket access. It would be helpful if you included any errors you're encountering.

Comment: @JerodG 


```TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond```

smth like that
and so, if there isnt much i can do with basic socket acces, is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Can you ping the other computer?

Comment: @JerodG I dont think i can ping the other one with my computer, we're not in local
But im not really good at WAN/LAN things, and i actually cant try

but anyways  i think i found a way to do it (or atleast a weird way to do what i want) using request module and not socket